# clang failed to find framework like 'AudioToolbox' 'CoreAudio'

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, clang, apple-m1

I'm trying ffmpeg on Apple M1. It seems clang has trouble finding xcode framework.
I'm pretty sure I have any of these in my xcode framework dir.

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'AudioToolbox'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'CoreAudio'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'AVFoundation'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'CoreVideo'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'CoreMedia'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'CoreGraphics'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'OpenGL'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'CoreImage'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'AppKit'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'VideoToolbox'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'CoreFoundation'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'CoreServices'
```

But If I delete `cmake-build-debug` and re-configure cmake project, the error disappeared and everything works fine.

Once I modified my `cmakelist.txt` I had to delete `cmake-build-debug` dir and re-configure.

Why is it?